# Updating the Chrome NaCl SDK for a Different OS

Tags: google-nativeclient

I need to download (update) my NaCl toolchain on my Mac Mini, but I don't have internet access where I am. I'm able to get my Windows laptop to a Wifi hotspot, but I can't see any option to download a pepper version for a different operating system.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NaCl updater uses this file to search for downloads:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/nativeclient-mirror/nacl/nacl_sdk/naclsdk_manifest2.json

If you examine the file in a text editor, you will see links to the different OS versions and you can download them using any computer.